# How to click on link inside a table that appears at three places with same name and same ID

Tags: css, ruby, capybara

I want to click on a link that is in table . There are three tabs and the values in the table change according to the choice of the tab.The link appears . So the link i want to click appears thrice(same link, same id). Now i want to click the link when i select the first tab. Since the Id is same at all places, it generates ambiguous error.

So i used the below code to click the link

```
find('tr:first-child > td:third-child [id^="gia0"]').click"
```

But i get the error "invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified". Please advice

Comment: How is that related to ruby?

Comment: Using the same ID more than once is invalid... You gotta fix the markup there. And you might wanna specify we're talking Cucumber/Capybara here just for people who don't recognize the syntax offhand.

Comment: Does your selector work somewhere else, e.g. in your browser?

Comment: As @ezuk said, it is not valid to have the same id more than once. It should be fixed. Let's assume you cannot fix it (it's not your website, etc.) then you could simply iterate over all the occurences of the id ("gia0") and add some unique value such as the iteration number, so the first time it is gia0_1, the second becomes gia0_2, etc. The id is now magically unique again, and should become "legal" (vs the "illegal" error you get now).

Answer (score 2):

I believe the "invalid selector" error is caused by this:

```
td:third-child
```

`:third-child` is not a selector that exists in CSS. You probably want to use the [`:nth-child(an+b)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child) selector instead, e.g.:

```
find('tr:first-child > td:nth-child(3) [id^="gia0"]').click
```

As others mentioned above, it's also a problem that your document has duplicate `id`s, but I'm not sure how or if that will manifest in Capybara.